# How to prove Fermat varieties in characteristic $p$ are unirational?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In  Shioda's famous paper "An Example of Unirational Surfaces in Characteristic $p$", the author proved that Fermat surface over $k$ with characteristic $p$
$$
x_1^n +x_2^n + x_3^n+x_4^n =0
$$
is unirational if $ q \equiv -1 (\text{mod } n)$ for some $p$-power $q$

At end of this paper, he mentioned that he proved it in high dimension case with similar method, i.e
$$ x_1^n +x_2^n + \cdots +x_{m+1}^n =0$$
is unirational if $m \geq 3$ is odd and $q \equiv -1 (\text{mod } n)$ for some $p$-power $q$.  But I can't prove it with his method in surface case. Is there any one know how to prove it?

Comment: I haven't worked out the proof, but there is [another paper by Shioda and Katsura](https://doi.org/10.2748/tmj/1178229881) where they prove what you want (Theorem III).